# Java - How do I rid of the last comma when outputting numbers from a for loop

Tags: java

So I'm running a program when a user is inputting a number and then I am printing out the odd numbers that come before this integer.

```
public class odd2 {

static Scanner UI = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print ( " Please enter a number ");

        if (UI.hasNextInt() )
        {
            int numberEntered = UI.nextInt();
        //define the limit


        System.out.println("Printing Odd numbers between 1 and " + numberEntered);

        for(int i=1; i < numberEntered; i++){

                //if the number is not divisible by 2 then it is odd
                if( i % 2 != 0){
                        System.out.print(i + ",");
                }
        }
```

Currently it prints out all numbers with a comma after them. Is there any way I can skip the ,. A solution I've though that might work it to create an array of these integers and then use stringToArray but I'd like to know if there is something easier I am missing.

Comment: System.out.print((i < numberEntered-1 ? i + "," : i ));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
System.out.print( (i == numberEntered - 1 || i == numberEntered - 2) ? i : i + ",");
```

Using a turnary operator to check if 'i' is the final value, then only printing the number.

Comment: Ternary operators are for affecting a value to a variable, this won't work.

Comment: @Berger Ternary operations are not only for assignment. http://ideone.com/DBzE4B

Comment: @Berger I tried it, it works. Not sure what you are talking about?

Comment: @cricket_007 :  then I learned something I wasn't aware of, thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks that works well!

Comment: @JavaSprinter mark solutions as solutions.